# This interaction failed on user click Discord Python Bot

Tags: button, discord, bots

I have a Python bot, when the user clicks on a button, I want it to execute the function verify but when I click the button, I get

> error This interaction failed

I don't know how to correctly trigger it since the
await verify(ctx)
Isn't working well

```
@client.command(name='channel')
async def channel(ctx):
    # Check if the command is used in a specific channel
    if ctx.channel.id != YOUR_SPECIFIC_CHANNEL_ID:
        await ctx.send('Ups! You need to type the command in the specified channel.')
        return

    # Check if the user has the required role to use the command
    required_role_id = 1096135568204767346  # Replace with the actual ID of the required role
    required_role = ctx.guild.get_role(required_role_id)

    if required_role not in ctx.author.roles:
        await ctx.send('You do not have the required role to use this command.')
        return

    # Create an embedded message
    embed = Embed(title="Welcome to the Server verifier.", description="", color=0x00ff00)
    embed.set_author(name="Server verifier", icon_url="icon")
    embed.add_field(name="Step 1", value="Please click the button below to start your verification", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Step 2", value="Follow all the instructions in direct message.", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="", value="***You need to have your direct messages enabled.***", inline=False)
    embed.set_footer(text="", icon_url="https://example.com/footer_icon.png")

    # Create a Button without a specific style
    button = discord.ui.Button(style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary, label="Start Verification", custom_id='start_verification')

    # Create a View with the Button
    view = discord.ui.View()
    view.add_item(button)

    # Send the embedded message with the view containing the button
    message = await ctx.send(embed=embed, view=view)

    # Function to check the button click
    def check(interaction):
        return interaction.custom_id == 'start_verification' and interaction.message.id == message.id and interaction.user.id == ctx.author.id

    # Wait for the user to click the button
    button_id = 'start_verification'
    interaction = await client.wait_for('button_click', check=lambda inter: check_button_click(inter, button_id))
    
    await interaction.defer()

    # Acknowledge the button click
    await interaction.response.send_message('Verification started.')

    # Call the verify function
    await verify(ctx)
```

here is the verify function

````
async def verify(ctx):
    # Generate a random string
    verification_code = ''.join(random.choices(string.digits, k=4))

    # Send a direct message with the code and add a reaction
    message = await ctx.author.send(f'Hey, {ctx.author.mention}! In order to update your Role, enter the following code in Serververifier.com chat. **```{verification_code}```**\n*This code is valid for 2 minutes.*\n\nReact with ✅ after typing the code.')
    await message.add_reaction('✅')  # You can use any emoji for the reaction

    # Function to check the reaction
    def check(reaction, user):
        return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) == '✅' and reaction.message.id == message.id

    # Wait for the user to react
    try:
        reaction, _ = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=120.0, check=check)
    except TimeoutError:
        await ctx.author.send(f'Verification timed out. Please click the button again in **#{ctx.guild.get_channel(YOUR_SPECIFIC_CHANNEL_ID).name}** channel')

        # Delete all private messages
        async for private_message in ctx.author.history(limit=None):
            await private_message.delete()

        # Send an embedded message on the specified channel
        channel_id_to_send_embed = 1180279701458128946  # Replace with the actual ID of your channel

        # Retrieve the previous nickname from the member's nickname before verification
        previous_nickname = ctx.author.display_name

        # Prepare the content for the embed
        embed_content = f"**Previous Nickname:** {previous_nickname}\n" \
                        f"**New Nickname:** {nickname}\n" \
                        f"**Roles Added:** {target_role.name}, {extra_role.name}"

        # Create an embedded message
        embed = Embed(title="Verification Success!", description=embed_content, color=0x00ff00)
        embed.set_author(name="Server Role Verifier",
                         icon_url="")
        embed.set_footer(text="Made by Server Verifier", icon_url="https://example.com/footer_icon.png")

        # Send the embedded message to the specified channel
        target_channel = await client.fetch_channel(channel_id_to_send_embed)
        if target_channel:
            await target_channel.send(embed=embed)
        else:
            print(f"Channel with ID {channel_id_to_send_embed} not found. Unable to send the verification success message.")

        return
    else:
        # User reacted with the correct emoji, execute the verification process
        await ctx.author.send('Getting your Roles')

        # The rest of the verification process (execute the rest of your code here)
        search_term = verification_code
        search_result = search_message_on_external_page(search_term)

        if search_result is None:
            await ctx.author.send(f'We could not find "{search_term}".Please restart the process.')
            return

        nickname, level = search_result

        user = ctx.author

        # Check if the external nickname already exists in the server for other users
        if nickname_exists(ctx.guild, user, nickname):
            await ctx.author.send(f'This Server account is associated with another Discord account. Please contact a moderator.')
            return

        # Check if the level is within the range of defined levels
        if 5 <= level <= 99:
            target_role_id = LEVEL_ROLES.get((level // 10) * 10)  # Use the integer division to round down to the nearest 10
        else:
            await ctx.author.send('Server Role Member is exclusive to users that achieve level 5+ on Server.com')
            return

        target_role = ctx.guild.get_role(target_role_id)
        extra_role = ctx.guild.get_role(EXTRA_ROLE_ID)

        if target_role and extra_role:
            # Remove existing level roles
            for role_id in LEVEL_ROLES.values():
                existing_role = ctx.guild.get_role(role_id)
                if existing_role and existing_role in user.roles:
                    await user.remove_roles(existing_role)

            # Add the roles to the user
            await user.add_roles(target_role, extra_role)

            # Print the extracted information
            print(f'Nickname: {nickname}')
            print(f'Level: {level}')

            # Update Discord username with the extracted nickname
            try:
                await user.edit(nick=nickname)
                await ctx.author.send(f'Roles "{target_role.name}" and "{extra_role.name}" added to you!\nNickname: {nickname}\nLevel: {level}\nUsername updated.')
            except discord.Forbidden:
                await ctx.author.send(f'Roles "{target_role.name}" and "{extra_role.name}" added to you!\nNickname: {nickname}\nLevel: {level}\nFailed to update username. Missing "manage_nicknames" permission.')

        else:
            await ctx.author.send(f'Target role for level {level} or extra role not found.')

        # Delete all private messages
        async for private_message in ctx.author.history(limit=None):
            await private_message.delete()

        # Send an embedded message on the specified channel
        channel_id_to_send_embed = 1180279701458128946  # Replace with the actual ID of your channel

        # Retrieve the Discord username (including discriminator) from the member
        discord_username = f"{ctx.author.name}#{ctx.author.discriminator}"

        # Prepare the content for the embed
        embed_content = f"**Discord Username:** {discord_username}\n" \
                        f"**New Nickname:** {nickname}\n" \
                        f"**Roles Added:** {target_role.name}, {extra_role.name}"

        # Create an embedded message
        embed = Embed(title="Verification Success!", description=embed_content, color=0x00ff00)
        embed.set_author(name="Server verifier",
                         icon_url="https://i.ibb.co/tsyqcVk/Captura-de-ecr-2023-12-01-215716-removebg-preview.png")
        embed.set_footer(text="", icon_url="https://example.com/footer_icon.png")

        # Send the embedded message to the specified channel
        target_channel = await client.fetch_channel(channel_id_to_send_embed)
        if target_channel:
            await target_channel.send(embed=embed)
        else:
            print(f"Channel with ID {channel_id_to_send_embed} not found. Unable to send verification success message.")

        # Delete all private messages
        async for private_message in ctx.author.history(limit=None):
            await private_message.delete()
````

```
async def check_button_click(interaction, button_id):
    return (
        interaction.custom_id == button_id
        and interaction.message.id == message.id  # Replace with the correct attribute
        and interaction.user.id == ctx.author.id  # Replace with the correct attribute
    )
```

I tried everything and nothing seems to trigger that verify function